# PHP | How to remove a specific string from the url string

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I am creating some pagination for my site and have everything working except one thing. The page displays a list coming from a DB with the option to hit next or previous based on what page you are on, this works fine. I also have a search function which uses a form with inputs and selects, I then use the $_GET variable to store the search requests in the url. The issue is when I hit the next or previous anchor tag it's href is linked to the same page with the next page number in the page= area of the url. So it basically deletes of the $_GET variables other than the page= part, which means i lose the search functions when i use the pagination buttons.

So what i have done so far is tried to make a variable that gets the $_GET variables of the current url and put it in a variable. I then delete the pagination part of that variable's string; so i can put in the anchor tag after the variable dealing with the pagination. Thus keeping the search request throughout each page.

I will provide some of my code below. I will try to take out all of the unnecessary parts to make this a little easier to read.

```
 <?php 

        //count how many results their are
        $count_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id FROM mls_listings_phrets");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($count_query);

        // get the current urls $_GET varibles (not finished)
        $getString = "&" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];


        //Pageination Starts here
        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_GET['page']);
        }else{
            $page = 1;
        }

        // limit per page
        $perPage = 10;

        $limit = "LIMIT " . ($page - 1)*$perPage . ", $perPage";

        $count_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id FROM mls_listings_phrets ORDER BY id DESC $limit");
        if($lastPage != 1){

            if($page != 1){
                $prev = $page -1;
                if(isset($_GET['keywordSeach'])){
                    $pagination .= '<a href="properties.php?page=' . $prev . $getString .'">Previous</a>';
                }else{
                    $pagination .= '<a href="properties.php?page=' . $prev . '">Previous</a>';
                }
            }

            if($page != $lastPage){
                $next = $page +1;
                if(isset($_GET['keywordSeach'])){
                    $pagination .= '<a href="properties.php?page=' . $next . $getString . '">Next</a>';
                }else{
                    $pagination .= '<a href="properties.php?page=' . $next . '">Next</a>';
                }
            }
        }
```

The $getString i know is not done yet. Ive tried using explode with the =  symbol and selecting the page section and deleting it. I also tried deleting the first x amount of letters from the string. Nothing has worked yet for me.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand too much, can you write an example of the starting string and the "finish" string (so, what you want to do) please?

Comment: Simply overwrite `$_GET['page']` with the page number of the next/previous page, and then use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to create a query string that contains all parameters from $_GET again. (Or, if you don’t want to manipulate values in $_GET directly, use `parse_str` first to get all GET parameters in an array.)

Answer (score 0):

```
// make an array with GET variables
$qs = array();

// get all existing GET variables except 'page'
foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
{
    if($key != 'page')
    {
        $qs[] = $key . '=' . $val;
    }
}

//add 'page' on the way you like
$qs[] = 'page=' . $prev;

// make the link
$pagination .= '<a href="properties.php?'.implode('&', $qs).'">Previous</a>';
```